# Authentication in webbrowser control in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication

I am navigating to web page in windows phone web browser control. How to detect whether the requested web page url is authenticated or not in web browser control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way as cookies in web browser control are inaccessible. If they were accessible we could have checked their value and it would have been easy.